# Unable to submit app to iTunes Connect using Organizer

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I'm having issues submitting an app to iTunes Connect using Organizer.

I build and archive my application successfully then go to Organizer. I successfully validate the application. I then click to submit the application to iTunes Connect. I get the dialog to choose signing certificate and the app that I am uploading. I submit that and after a short time it comes back with the following error:
[image]

I know that I am entering my apple id and password correctly. As far as I can tell the bundle identifier and the rest of the app metadata are correct.

Has anyone seen this before or have any advice?

(I have tried using the App Uploader and get similar results).

10.6.4.
And latest version of SDK and xcode.

Comment: Have you submitted an application before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW There doesn't seem to be an answer to this. I did however, uninstall Application Loader completely and reinstall it and the upload has worked.